# What is the latest version of ThinkPad laptops that doesn't have Intel Management Engine or similar remote controller built-in?

Tags: laptop, processor, intel, security

I work in cybersecurity and would like to find an older laptop that doesn't have the Intel Management Engine built-in, while still able to run a Debian OS well.

I have an IBM ThinkPad t42 with 42T0273 system board laying around, which was introduced in late 2004. While it likely doesn't have IME on it, I found that t42s came equipped with something called Embedded Security System, which sounds eerily similar.

Can you advise on whether my t42 is safe to use, or is there another, perhaps later model of thinkpads that can be used safely? (I do not want to use system76 or purism systems).

Comment: IME can be [partially disabled](https://github.com/corna/me_cleaner). There are also many ThinkPad models with an AMD CPU that don't have IME at all. (But may have similar functionality made by AMD)

Comment: All Intel chipsets have IME (since 2008), so you need either an old thinkpad or buy an AMD system. The Thinkpad T14 gen 2 looks pretty good